# Merge Pandas DataFrames on Two Column Values Irrespective of Order in Row

Tags: python, pandas, merge

Given two dataframes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['Red', 'Blu', 1.1],
                   ['Yel', 'Blu', 2.1],
                   ['Grn', 'Grn', 3.1]], columns=['col_1a','col_1b','score_1'])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['Blu', 'Red', 1.2],
                   ['Yel', 'Blu', 2.2],
                   ['Vio', 'Vio', 3.2]], columns=['col_2a','col_2b','score_2'])
```

I want to merge them on two columns like below:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame([
                   ['Blu', 'Red', 1.1, 1.2],
                   ['Yel', 'Blu', 2.1, 2.2],
                   ], columns=['col_a','col_b','score_1','score_2'])
```

Caveat 1: The order of column contents can switch between dataframes to merge.  The first row, for example, should be merged because it contains both "Red" and "Blue" even if they appear in different columns.

Caveat 2: The order of columns in the final `df_3` is unimportant.  Whether "Blu" is in `col_a` or `col_b` doesn't mean anything.

Caveat 3: Anything else not matching, like the last row, is ignored

Comment: can you show what your merging gave you and  how you actually want it to look like?

Comment: merge `df_1` and `df_2` to look like `df_3` based on the first two columns of each df.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a type-o? If I will merge `df1` and `df2` then I will get a dataframe with only one row. That is, I think  `['Red', 'Blu', 1.1]` should be `['Blu', 'Red', 1.1]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can sort the first two columns along the rows, then merge on them:

```
# rename column names
cols = ['col_a', 'col_b']
df1.columns = cols + ['score_1']
df2.columns = cols + ['score_2']

# sort the two id columns along the row
df1[cols] = pd.np.sort(df1[cols], axis=1)
df2[cols] = pd.np.sort(df2[cols], axis=1)

# merge
df1.merge(df2)
```

[image]